# floating a div with jquery/offset - ignores href hashtag

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, hashmap

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = $('#rt_outer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#rt_outer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#rt_outer').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#rt_outer').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The problem is fairly straight forward. If I use a header redirect to a new location in the page (say half way down, I jump to #halfway after processing a php script using header("somepage.php#halfway") the div container which is handled by this script won't jump down until the page is scrolled in either direction.

I know there is a solution to this, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of John Koerner's response I was able to do a bit of research and come up with a solution. You can see it in action at http://www.colonelcoon.net?override=true/

Here's the code I ended up using...

```
<script src="http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/raw/v1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

var top = $('#rt_outer').offset().top - parseFloat($('#rt_outer').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));

  function checkScroll() {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('#rt_outer').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('#rt_outer').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  }

  $(window).hashchange(function (event) {
      checkScroll();
  });

  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
      checkScroll();
  });

  $(window).hashchange();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Window's hashchange event:

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
   console.log('hash changed'); 
});​
```

For your solution you could extract your scroll code to a function and then call the function from both the scroll and hashchange handlers.

Comment: The hash is being loaded on a redirect, it's not being used in a javascript call (which I guess would be one way to do it)..

Check this out, http://www.colonelcoon.net?override=true - then click on the comments link in the second blog/news panel in the center. You'll see what it's doing.

Comment: I did not realize that hashchange is a plugin. I was able to come up with a solution based on your direction. Thanks a bunch!